# Mac OS X drawing program

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

I want to write a ray tracer for a Mac. I don't want to learn Objective-C, is it possible to mix C++ and Objective-C? Is there some simple example somewhere of a program that does that and draws on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDL work on OS X and should work seamlessly with C++ code.

http://www.libsdl.org/

Comment: I should add, there are lots of examples, so it should be pretty easy for you to find code that does what you want in terms of drawing straightaway.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely mix C++ and Objective-C is called Objective-C++.

Basically you use Objective-C for the UI and all your logic and controllers can be done using C++. You don't need too much objective-c to do this. If you have a little time for this approach I definitely recommend it is incredibly powerful. (many Apple frameworks do this way)

But if you don't want to learn Objective-c at all you can use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) too. OpenCV is a bunch of of algorithms for image processing, computer vision, machine learning, AR, tracking, etc. It has some basic UI elements (windows, buttons, slide bars, etc) which you will find useful. You only need C++! and it will work in many OSs